Is Riskfolio's HCPortfolio working right?
enter image description hereThis is a portion of my project where it yields the following graphic.
I noticed how the correlation between EWH and MCHI (which is usually move in parallel to each other) is fairly low, hinting that something is wrong.
(Working on 2019-2024 monthly data)
Also, I crossed-check the result with my Bloomberg terminal, which yield a fiarly high 0.8 beta.
import riskfolio as rp

# Plotting Assets Clusters

ax = rp.plot_clusters(returns=monthly_returns,
                       codependence='pearson',
                       linkage='ward',
                       k=None,
                      opt_k_method = 'twodiff',
                       max_k=10,
                       leaf_order=True,
                       dendrogram=True,
                       linecolor=None

I'm not sure if this is an issue around mislabeling the tickers to the chart, but I wouldn't like to think that the lib handles such task incorrectly. Therefore, I have not clue now.
I'm asking if there is anything I should check.
Thank you in advance :)

Welcome to SO! Please make your case, by providing a [mre], as recommended in [ask]. First we'd need a representative sample of input data and your expected output.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you checked StackOverflow and Github for similar issues?
